# Android exception accesing a resource

Tags: android

I am getting following exception at line 1414 from a fragment.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{2104037} not attached to Activity
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:715)
                                                                               at com.juarezserver.citystatus.fragment.HomeFragment.addMarker(HomeFragment.java:1414)
```

This is the piece of code involved:

```
if (tiporeporte.equals("1")){

            int height = 75;
            int width = 75;
            BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tipo_1);//line 1414
            Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
            Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);


            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker));
        }
```

I don´t know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919240/fragment-myfragment-not-attached-to-activity

Comment: Where do you have that piece of code in your fragment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragment-not-attached-to-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672883/java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragment-not-attached-to-activity)

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi, it is inside a method that retrieves markers from a remote server. The issue is not taking place always, only sometimes

Comment: And from where is that method called?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tipo_1);
```

where you try to access the resources through **getResources()** and your fragment is not attached yet.

Try to call that code block in your Fragment's [onAttache()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)) or any other lifecycle event where the Fragment's Activity is ready.

Please check the Fragment's lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: The problem is at the line itself. I have removed it and changed the way to get the drawable here : markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tipo_1)); and now it works without issues.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call 
`(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tipo_1);//line 1414` before fragment has been attached to an Activity. First wait for Fragment to Attach an activity and then you can call `yourConvertView.getResources().***` Where yourConvertView is a View which you got on `OnCreateView()` of Fragment

**Update**
This may help Someone.
Replaced 
`(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tipo_1);//line 1414` 
 
With 
`markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.dr‌​awable.tipo_1));`
 and it worked

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess you are not right. The problem is not happening always, if you were right, the issue should always appear.

Comment: I went through the same behavior once and later I found this reason.

Comment: OK then, but I don´t know what to do with your proposal.

Comment: The problem is at the line itself. I have removed it and changed the way to get the drawable here : markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tipo_1)); and now it works without issues.Thank you

Comment: Thank you for informing back!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried changing the way to get the drawable, and the problem is gone.

```
if (tiporeporte.equals("1")){

            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tipo_1));
        }
```