# Open new Activity from Fragment on click to listView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I want to open new Activity from listView on Click method that is inside fragment. I Implement separate file for my adapter and try to open new Activity from click listener method. But when I try to open this activity it shows my an error. Error show that there is an mistake on line where I call this:

```
 ((Activity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(intentBlock, position);
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: esticrm.pl.esticall, PID: 28410
>                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CallsFragment{7b054bc} not attached to Activity
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1026)
>                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1017)
>                                                                            at esticrm.pl.esticall.CallListAdapter$3.onClick(CallListAdapter.java:137)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6199)
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23647)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

**Adapter file where I set my onClickListener**

```
public class CallListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CallList> {

public CallListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CallList> calls) {
    super(context, 0, calls);
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CallList callList = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.call_list, parent, false);
    }
        block.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intentBlock = new Intent(view.getContext(), BlockCallActivity.class);

            intentBlock.putExtra("number", num);
            intentBlock.putExtra("authToken", authToken);


            ((Activity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(intentBlock, position);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672883/java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragment-not-attached-to-activity/28673167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post Activity as a param and call activity.startActivity()

Use below code

```
public class CallListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CallList> {
    Activity activity;
    public CallListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CallList> calls,Activity activity) {
        super(context, 0, calls);
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CallList callList = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.call_list, parent, false);
        }
        block.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intentBlock = new Intent(view.getContext(), BlockCallActivity.class);

                intentBlock.putExtra("number", num);
                intentBlock.putExtra("authToken", authToken);


                activity.startActivityForResult(intentBlock, position);
            }
        });
    }
}
```