# Recreate Actual Fragment when MenuItem is selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

i want to recreate (reload) a fragment when i click on a OptionsItem from a Drawer Navigation Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.fr:
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(getBaseContext(), "Fr");
                if(getVisibleFragment().isAdded()){
                    getVisibleFragment().getActivity().recreate();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.ar:
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(getBaseContext(), "Ar");
                if(getVisibleFragment().isAdded()){
                    getVisibleFragment().getActivity().recreate();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.en:
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(getBaseContext(), "En");
                if(getVisibleFragment().isAdded()){
                    getVisibleFragment().getActivity().recreate();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.es:
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(getBaseContext(), "Es");
                if(getVisibleFragment().isAdded()){
                    getVisibleFragment().getActivity().recreate();
                }
                return true;
        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

when i click on an Option i get this error :

**`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment NewsMainFragment{9a39a2f} not attached to a context`**

how can i achieve this properly ?

Comment: As far my knowledge says you can not recreate a fragment or activity!, You can refer  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672883/java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragment-not-attached-to-activity)

Recreation of fragments can be accessed via newInstrance() method.

`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, YourFragment.newInstance()).commit();`

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
getVisibleFragment().getActivity().recreate();
```

you recreate the whole `activity`, not the `fragment`. So, if the `fragment` you want recreate is in the `activity` where the method `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` placed, you just recreate current activity, so you can call just:

```
recreate();
```

instead of your code.

But if you want just to recreate the `fragment` without recreating whole `activity`, you can put the code, where you initialize all views of your `fragment`, in separate public method and call them, like:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUi();
    }

    public void updateUi() {
        // Your code
    }
```

and then:

```
case R.id.fr:
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(getBaseContext(), "Fr");
                if(getVisibleFragment().isAdded()){
                    ((YourFragment)getVisibleFragment()).updateUi();
                }
                return true;
```

Comment: i tried to use recreate(); bu ti get the same error