# fragment not attached to activity on volley response

Tags: android, android-volley

I get the following error which I think means my activity is null

```
fragment not attached to activity on volley response
```

How can I fix this issue?
These are my codes

```
  MainActivity._MainActivity_.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity._MainActivity_, "inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                   Activity activity = getActivity();
                   if(activity != null){
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(define, SaveNewFactor.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                    }else {
                        Log.i("myLog","activity is null");
                    }
```

[my logcat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuQGg.jpg)

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: I added an image from the logcat

Comment: You can have reference of the same kind of issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28673131/8473587 , Your Activity object might be null or else the refernace of Activity is not currect.

Comment: From where you call the fragment?

Comment: Intent activity2Intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraActivity.class);
                startActivity(activity2Intent);     Try Something like this

Comment: @Hardik Vegad  I saw that link but still didn't figure out how to fix my problem

Comment: @Ruben-Meiring  I defined it in the MainActivity

Comment: @Ruben Meiring It didn't work for me

Comment: Checkout Eventbus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Actually the code you provided does not provide proper understanding of your main issue, I am posting an answer is you are talking about the intent that you have implmented to start the activity SaveNewFector.class then don't use the MainAcitivyt_mainActivity_ in 1st parameter of the intent, instead use SheetSaveNewFector.this.

Answer (score 0):

i haven`t see you fragment in your code..
but i think.. maybe your network response comes too late, and after your fragment detach

Comment: this needs to be a comment not an answer

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I run the code, the activity is null log is printed but I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Change the Intent to start the activity SaveNewFector.class

```
Intent intent=new Intent(SheetSaveNewFector.this,SaveNewFector.class);  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you. But SheetSaveNewFactor is not a Activity . SheetSaveNewFactor extends BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: BottomSheetDialogFragment is itself had a context like dialog for that you can use only "this" to get the context, so in that case you might use getContent() for starting new activity, Like 

Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),SaveNewFector.class);

I suggest put some debug points and check on which exect line you are getting this crash.