# I'm getting "not attached to an activity" error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-fragmentactivity

In my main activity, I'm using navigation component to switch between the fragments,

I'm fetching data from my backend, the data received successfully then I'm updating my UI,
I'm getting this error for one of my fragment,

for this code

```
 Converters.getSpannableString(
                    ""name,
                    0,
                    2,
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        requireActivity(),
                        R.color.lightSpanRed
                    )



on this line I'm getting crash:- ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(),R.color.lightSpanRed)
```

the Logs is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MainFragment{ce669b1} (aa1b0f2b-de44-443a-834e- 
ee9e10df261b)} not attached to an activity.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:833)
```

I'm getting this error, can anyone provide the best answer

Comment: Where exactly u r using this particular line of code in fragment? add it with question

Comment: @ADM Question is updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672883/java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragment-not-attached-to-activity)

Comment: you can use `getActivity()` instead of `requireActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

You must check the method in which you are executing this `code`.

You can use `requireContext()` instead of `requireActivity`.

Or

You can safely unwrap it is specified in the comments.

```
activity?.let {
            Converters.getSpannableString(
                "",
                0,
                2,
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    it,
                    R.color.colorPrimaryDark
                )
            )
        }
```

Comment: This is treating the symptom of the problem, but not the root cause. If any callback is happening after the fragment is detached from the activity, that's already a memory leak and bigger problem that needs to be fixed. Fixing that root issue would make this covering up of the larger issue irrelevant.

Comment: You can use `lifecyclescope` for that.